# Multiple Notification In laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, notifications

I want to create multiple notification eg: if a user register then, a notification must be generated
`$user->notify(new NewUserNotification($user));`
created using notify it created notification perfectly

```
'e9e92865-fcca-4e35-8b2d-7e900f80ddd6', 
'App\\Notifications\\NewUserNotification', 'App\\User', '10', 
'{\"name\":\"bonnykapoor\",\"email\":\"bonnykapoor111591@mail.com\"}', 
NULL, '2020-06-01 11:03:17', '2020-06-01 11:03:17'
```

now i can fetch this notification from user model,but when i want to create and fetch notification for different model i can create the notification but can't fetch the data

```
$staff->notify(new NewstaffNotification($staff));
'e9e92865-fcca-4e35-8b2d-7e900f80ddd6', 
'App\\Notifications\\NewstaffNotification', 'App\\staff', '18', 
'{\"name\":\"bonkapoor\",\"email\":\"bonkapoor111591@mail.com\"}', 
NULL, '2020-06-01 11:03:17', '2020-06-01 11:03:17'
```

notification can be created but, can't fetch the data...

Comment: Did you include `Notifiable` trait in your `Staff` model?

Comment: Yes,i can create notification for different model,but i can't fetch notification data for different models

Comment: How are you fetching notification data?

Comment: ```  foreach (Auth::user()->notifications as $notification) {
        //             echo $notification;
        //         }```

Comment: You are doing it wrong. User notification can be found on Auth::user() model, and staff notification can be found on staff object. Do you have any relation with user and staff?

Comment: No,there is no relationship between user model and staff model,but i can fetch notification from user model using this code ```foreach (Auth::user()->notifications as $notification) { // echo $notification; // }```  but,can't fetch data from notification from staff model using this code   ```foreach (staff()->notifications as $notification) { // echo $notification; // }```

Comment: Your approach is wrong. What does staff() returns?

Comment: Noting,i wanted to fetch notifications from staff

Comment: Get a `staff` object from db via Staff model, then you can fetch that `staff`'s notification.

Comment: I have already initialize staff model in my view ```<?php $staff = App\staff; foreach ($staff->notifications as $notification) { // echo $notification; // } ?>``` still i didn't got my staff notification